# Access index property in javascript using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api

The api that i am messing with has a limit of 100 items per request. So I am trying to find out the length variable (which works) but why cant i use that variable to get the index. like below.

```
var ttl = results.data.length;
const s = results.data[ttl].id;
```

console reads

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

`ttl` does not work. But if i do the following...

```
const s = results.data[100].id;
```

The value is recognized fine... But I don't know what the length will be so I need to set it in a var and try to navigate the object with the length var?

Comment: `ttl = parseInt(l);` cannot work because you declared `ttl` as **`const`**.

Comment: if the length of an array is 2, it contains elements 0 and 1 (but not 2)  so array[array.length] will always be undefined.

Comment: I know how the index works I just want to reach it dynamically... I tried changing const to var with no luch

Comment: Also, if `results.data` is an array, then `results.data.length` is already a number. There is no need to call `parseInt`.

Comment: @Felix Kling See the edits to what I am trying above... Still didnt work

Comment: *"I know how the index works"* Apparently not. If `data.length` is `2` then only `data[0]` and `data[1]` exist. Accessing `data[2]` (what you are doing) will return `undefined`. And `undefined.id` throws an error.

Comment: *"use that variable to get the index"* What exactly is the "index" you want to get? Do you mean getting the value *at* that index? As mentioned earlier, the *length* of the array is not a valid index *into* the array. `length` is always the highest index + 1.

Comment: If you use the length of an array as the index to get a value from it, you will always be out of the arrays bounds. `myarray = [a, b, c]` has a length of 3, but `myarray[3]` is out of bounds, the array only has indexes 0, 1, 2.

Comment: Year 2017. Browsers come with excellent dev tools. You could insert a break point somewhere in your code (for example by using `debugger` statement) and debug it. Debugger would allow you to inspect what is current `ttl` value, if there is something at `data[ttl]` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write over a const. What `ttl = parseInt(l);` means? What you were trying to do? (The code refers to the original version of the question)

```
const ttl = results.data.length;
ttl = parseInt(l); // <- It's wrong
const s = results.data[ttl].id;
```

To get the last value you just need this:

```
const s = results.data[results.data.length-1].id;
```

Comment: `results.data.length-1` that worked!... I will mark it in 6 mins

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with `ttl` being a const

Comment: @jonathanGB: It was a problem in the original question. But I guess it wasn't the OPs actual code otherwise they would have gotten a different error.